# Rails twitter gem search function not limiting count of tweets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am using the twitter gem to search tweets and I want to limit my search results to 10 tweets per function call. I am using the following function

```
class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    @tweets = $twitter.search("google", options = {count: 10})
  end
end
```

but I still get thousands of tweets back and it is using up my api rate limits in a couple of page loads

I also tried

```
        @tweets = $twitter.search("google", count: 10)
```

and

```
    @tweets = $twitter.search("google", count: => 10, :result_type => "recent")
```

But it never takes the count variable into consideration and does not limit number of tweets fetched. I followed the documentation here http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Search but I don't understand why it does not work

Comment: What version are you using? What if you try with the parameter `rpp` instead of `count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@tweets = $twitter.search("google",:result_type => "recent").take(10)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, why does take limit the api calls? and not the parameters?